# Color nodes based on type/attribute

Tags: neo4j, graph-visualization

I am building a network using the following code:

```
match (n) detach delete n;

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data-assets.csv' AS data
Create (:Data {id: data.Id, dataName: data.Name, Type: data.Type});

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data-links.csv' AS links
match (d1:Data {id:links.Source}), (d2:Data {id:links.Target})
CREate (d1)-[:Feed]->(d2);
```

Where:

- `data-assets.csv` has the columns: `Id`, `Name` and `Type`
- `data-links.csv` has the columns: `Source` ,`Target`

I want to have different colors of the nodes depending on their types. I found [this](https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-can-i-create-relationships-in-neo4j-cypher-from-a-csv-that-depend-on-the-type-of-nodes/20615?u=drorata) and [this](https://community.neo4j.com/t/coloring-nodes-in-neo4j-depending-on-property/12287?u=drorata) but probably I'm too new to neo4j to know how to make it work.

Comment: What tool do you use for visualization?

Comment: Desktop version of Neo4j.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful? https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-browser/#browser-styling-adv